cypress:xvfb malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)
I am trying to run cypress tests on Jenkins (using chrome browser and in headless mode). Also, there is a requirement that we need to publish the video recording of each run to the cypress dashboard.
This is the cypress_run.sh file that I have:
# Update package list
apt-get update

# Install NVM (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

# Load NVM
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# Use NVM to install the specified version of Node.js
nvm install 20

# Use npm to install the specified version of npm
npm install -g npm@9

echo "Running Cypress Command"
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

echo "Installed NPM Packages!"
export CYPRESS_BASE_URL="$UNIFIED_URL"
export CYPRESS_USERNAME="admin"
export CYPRESS_PASSWORD="password"
echo "Cypress base Url: ${CYPRESS_BASE_URL}"

unset DISPLAY
DISPLAY= npx cypress run --record --key <KEY> --browser chrome --headless --config-file cypress.config.js --config baseUrl="$CYPRESS_BASE_URL" username="$CYPRESS_USERNAME" password="$CYPRESS_PASSWORD"

This file is being called from a Makefile which in turn runs the command within a docker image. Here is the Makefile target for your reference:
run-cypress:
    docker run --rm --entrypoint "/bin/bash" \
         --network host \
         -e REPO21_USR=${REPO21_USR} \
         -e REPO21_PSW=${REPO21_PSW} \
         -e UNIFIED_URL=${UNIFIED_URL} \
         -e USERNAME=${UNIFIED_USER} \
         -e PASSWORD=${UNIFIED_PASSWORD} \
         -e COMMIT_INFO_SHA="$(shell git rev-parse HEAD)" \
         -e COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE="$(shell echo "$(shell git log --format=%B -n 1)" | sed 's/"//g')" \
         -e COMMIT_INFO_AUTHOR="$(shell git log --format='%an' -n 1)" \
         -e COMMIT_INFO_EMAIL="$(shell git log --format='%ae' -n 1)" \
         -e DEBUG=cypress:* \
         -v ${JSP_SRC_DIR}/test/e2e-ui/cypress:/e2e/cypress \
         -v ${JSP_SRC_DIR}/test/e2e-ui/cypress.config.js:/e2e/cypress.config.js \
         -v ${JSP_SRC_DIR}/test/e2e-ui/cypress_run.sh:/e2e/cypress_run.sh \
         -v ${JSP_SRC_DIR}/test/e2e-ui/package.json:/e2e/package.json \
         -v ${JSP_SRC_DIR}/test/e2e-ui/tsconfig.json:/e2e/tsconfig.json \
         -v ${JSP_SRC_DIR}/test/e2e-ui/webpack.config.js:/e2e/webpack.config.js \
         -w /e2e <domain>/cypress/included-jf-cli:13.6.4 ./cypress_run.sh

When I am triggering the build, the build fails every time with the error message:
Error Message
And finally the test fails with the message:
[1132:0402/200601.485116:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY

[1132:0402/200601.485165:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

I have tried manually setting the DISPLAY environment variable, but that does not seem to help. It kept on failing even after that.
